# Rendering the partial View in the correct table row

Tags: jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have View where the values are populated in a table. There is a link to generate another table(Partial View) which needs to be displayed exactly below the row from where the link was clicked. As seen in the figure below when *View Properties*  is clicked from the thirs row, the result is displayed below the first row.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.links').click(function () {
        $('.View').toggle();

    });
});
</script>
```

Relevant part of the View

```
<tr>
    <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="@item.DescriptionDE">@Html.ActionLink(item.OptionName, "ViewOptionValues", "OptionValues", new { id = item.OptionID }, null)</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.TechnicalCharacteristic.TCName, "ViewTcSet", "TechnicalCharacteristics", new {id = item.TechnicalCharacteristicID },null)</td>
    <td class="links">
         @Ajax.ActionLink("View Properties", "ViewOptionvalues", "Options", new { id = item.OptionID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="ViewProperty"})|
         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OptionID })|
         @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.OptionID })|
         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OptionID })
     </td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none;overflow-x:auto" class="View"><td colspan="3"><div id="ViewProperty" style="overflow:auto"></div></td></tr>
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggle()` And remove `id="ViewProperty"` - your generating invalid html with duplicate `id` attributes but you will also need to modify the `Ajax.ActionLink()` (just use jquery/ajax instead)

Comment: Now the correct `tr` is being toggles. But the View is not being rendered. None of the values for UpdateTargetID in `Ajax.ActionLink()` works. And am I not using Ajax/Jquery now?

Comment: No I mean `$.ajax()` or simply `$.load()` (get rid of the obsolete `Ajax.ActionLink()` method). You have invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes. `UpdateTargetId="ViewProperty"}` updates only the first element with `id="ViewProperty"` and `$('.View').toggle();` toggles all rows

Comment: How do I give the link to the function call? As a button? Give me 10 mins to try something in your method. I really do not know what i should do. But i just found an example for a button click. I have to pass a parameter to render the partial view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating invalid html because you have multiple elements with `<div id="ViewProperty" ...>`. Your `Ajax.ActionLink()` has the option `UpdateTargetId="ViewProperty"` which will only ever return the first element with `id="ViewProperty"` (not the element in the next row). And finally, in your script, `$('.View').toggle();` toggles all rows with `class="View"`.

Delete the (obsolete) `Ajax.ActionLink()` method and replace with

```
<tr>
  ....
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="view" data-id="@item.OptionID">View Properties<a> | @Html.ActionLink(...
  </td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none;overflow-x:auto"><td colspan="3"><div style="overflow:auto"></div></td></tr>
```

And then modify your script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ViewOptionvalues", "Options")';
$('.view').click(function() {
  var nextRow = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
  $.get(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function(response) {
    nextRow.find('div').html(response);
    nextRow.toggle();
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. only the `tr` is being toggled. I debugged and the function is being called. and returns View.

Comment: Do you mean the controller methods returns a `View`? It should return a `PartialView` And see update - it should have been `.find('div')` not `.children('div')`

Comment: Yes. It worked. Worked both on Partial View and View. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And you will probably want to include a flag so that its not loaded again if the user clicks it again (just toggles the visibility - and perhaps change the link text to "Hide Properties")

Comment: Now if the user clicks it twice the display is being toggled. and when different properties are clicked it is beign displayed the right way. May be I could change the link text. :)

Comment: Its being toggled, but its also making another unnecessary call to the server. Just add something like - `if ($(this).data('isloaded')) { nextRow.toggle(); } else { $(this).data('isloaded', true), $.get(.....` after the `var nextRow = ` line of code

Comment: Yes sure. I will do that.